# Can't access array value with keys generated from SimpleXML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, wordpress, rss

I'm taking the Wordpress XML default export and trying to merge the post RSS with the images RSS. I first grab all the images and associated post IDs, and throw them in an array. Then I run through every blog post, and grab an image from the array using the post ID.

First I grab each XML item and add them to an array. I use the post ID I get as the array key to access later.

```
foreach($xml_image->channel->item as $featured) {
  // add image attachment url to $image array with post_id as key
  $url = $featured->guid->__toString();
  $post_id = intval($featured->children($ns['wp'])->post_id->__toString());
  $image[$post_id] = $url;
  //var_dump($url);
  //var_dump($post_id);
}
```

This outputs as

```
Array ( [62] => http://image.url.com )
```

Cool. Then when I try to access it by using a variable, or even hard coding the key/number, it doesn't work

```
$image_url = $image[62];

Outputs: Notice: Undefined offset: 62 in /home/filename.php on line whatever
```

I've tried converting this array to an object and accessing the keys that way (`$imageobj = (object) $image); $imageobj->{62};`) and that also doesn't work. I've tried using `(int)` and `intval()` and they haven't worked. Even a trim() and (string). And I finally settled on `__toString()`, even though it doesn't work either.

I'm not sure what the `SimpleXmlElement` function is doing to the integer to make `62 != 62`, or how I would begin to replicate the 62 in the format neccessary to access it.

I've even tried array_search and array_filter, making the post id and element in the array (`id=>$post_id`) instead of the key itself -- nada.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. This code is based off https://github.com/greywillfade/wpxml-to-kirby, just adding the above foreach loop function on top (with a separate file load and all that jazz).

Comment: are you sure your target array is `$image` ? seem it not initialized !

Comment: from your code maybe should be: $image_url = $url[62];

Comment: How about $image[$post_id][62] ?

Comment: It would be useful if you would share some sample data from the XML file.  It's easier to test exact circumstances only with original data.